# strange nginx error log file: connection to a private ip from a public ip

Tags: nginx, log-files, private-ip

On a vps I have configured a vpn (wireguard) where the IP is `10.6.6.100`.

I found this strange log on `nginx` `error.log`:

```
2023/11/01 03:52:22 [error] 2821800#2821800: *135455 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/KghB" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: <a public IP omitted>, server: 10.6.6.100, request: "GET /KghB HTTP/1.1", host: "<an host omitted>"
```

the IP is for sure used by a script scanning tool.

how it is possible that it was able to contact the server on the private IP used by the vpn (`10.6.6.100`) ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please add the output of `nginx -T` to your question so we can see full nginx configuration.